# Are sockets allowed to be global in C?

Tags: c, sockets, global-variables, sendto, recvfrom

I'm making a program that is constantly checking to receive and send data through a socket, and I have the socket declared globally and it's used inside 2 thread functions. I setup the socket in main(), and one thread uses recvfrom using the socket and that works fine but whenever I try and call sendto it returns a value < 0 which confuses me since recvfrom is working fine.

Comment: What is the error? Check `errno`. Possibly `EMSGSIZE`?

Comment: not sure about the title of your question, but in general yes.

Comment: Sockets are allowed to be global, but using the same socket in two different threads is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @user3386109: There shouldn't be a problem for one thread sending and another thread receiving.

Comment: Either way, I suppose we'll need to see OP's code before this can be resolved. More at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> Are sockets allowed to be global in C?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

A socket is simply a class of file descriptor, which in C is represented by an `int` value.  The important thing here is **the value** you store for the socket (that is filled when you first call `socket(2)` and doesn't change until you free it in the kernel with `close(2)`).  As a system provided value, it is maintained until you free it with `close(2)` or the process terminates (by any means).  The place where you store that value (a global, static or automatic variable) doesn't mind.

So finally the answer is **yes**.